# CPU Intensive Calculation Examples?

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu-usage

I need a few easily implementable single cpu and memory intensive calculations that I can write in java for a test thread scheduler.

They should be slightly time consuming, but more importantly resource consuming.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Martin: everybody knows already that's 42.

Comment: @Martin: "42+0 = ?" sounds like a good bet :) Sorry for spamming meursault's question, I found it too funny to resist. I'll stop now and go check on my million monkeys and typewriters project in the basement.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A few easy examples of CPU-intensive tasks:

- searching for prime numbers (involves lots of BigInteger divisions)
- calculating large factorials e.g. 2000! ((involves lots of BigInteger multiplications)
- many Math.tan() calculations (this is interesting because Math.tan is native, so you're using two call stacks: one for Java calls, the other for C calls.)

Answer (score 7):

Multiply two matrices. The matrices should be huge and stored on the disk.

String search. Or, index a huge document (detect and count the occurrence of each word or strings of alphabets) For example, you can index all of the identifiers in the source code of a large software project.

Calculate pi.

Rotate a 2D matrix, or an image.

Compress some huge files.

...

Comment: Or just append to StringBuilder in a forloop over N seconds.

Comment: this will also involve a lot of IO, so the resource consumption will be IO intense than being CPU intense

Answer (score 6):

The CPU soak test for the PDP-11 was `tan(atan(tan(atan(...)))` etc. Works the FPU pretty hard and also the stack and registers.

Answer (score 4):

Ok this is not Java, but this is based on [Dhrystone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhrystone) benchmark algorithm found [here](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/dhry-c). These implementations of the algorithm might give you an idea on how is it done. The link [here](http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/index.htm) contains sources to C/C++ and Assembler to obtain the benchmarks.

Answer (score 4):

- Calculate nth term of the fibonacci series, where n is greater than 70. (time consuming)
- Calculate factorials of large numbers. (time consuming)
- Find all possible
  paths between two nodes, in a graph. (memory consuming)

Comment: I tried with Java BigInteger and even calculating the 5000th number in the Fibonacci series was done very quickly.

Comment: @iamcreasy Can you post some working code for doing that (on ideone maybe) ? I am curious how it happened so fast.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Official RSA Challenge](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2094)
2. Unofficial RSA Challenge - Grab some ciphertext that you want to read in plaintext.  Let the computer at it.  If u use a randomized algorithm, there is a small but non-zero chance that u will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around with Thread priority in Java and used the code below. It seems to keep the CPU busy enough that the thread priority makes a difference.

```
@Test
public void testCreateMultipleThreadsWithDifferentPriorities() throws Exception {
    class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<1_000_000; i++) {
                double d = tan(atan(tan(atan(tan(atan(tan(atan(tan(atan(123456789.123456789))))))))));
                cbrt(d);
            }
            LOGGER.debug("I am {}, and I have finished", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
    final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 32;
    List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<Thread>(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
    for (int i=1; i<=NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        if (i == NUMBER_OF_THREADS) {
            // Last thread gets MAX_PRIORITY
            t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
            t.setName("T-" + i + "-MAX_PRIORITY");
        } else {
            // All other threads get MIN_PRIORITY
            t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
            t.setName("T-" + i);
        }
        threadList.add(t);
    }

    threadList.forEach(t->t.start());
    for (Thread t : threadList) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```