# Code stolen by the compiler, how do I circumvent its criminal ways

Tags: c++, multithreading, compiler-construction, for-loop, compiler-optimization

I wanted to stress out the processor on a new computer at work. I figured a good way to do it would be to open a thread for each processor with the function:

```
void soStressful() {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        j += i;
    }
}
```

But for some reason the compiler takes this code away. (Because the program runs instantly regardless of the complexity of the calculation or the size of i)  and we also log very little cpu usage.

**How can I stop the compiler for compiling out this code?**

Comment: It "takes it away" (optimizes it) because it's useless (taking it away has no observable side effects). Try printing the result. I doubt this code would take nearly any time to execute anyway.

Comment: when j = 0, stackoverflow because i+1/j devides by 0

Comment: What compiler are you using? Also you have a divide by zero exception since j is zero.

Comment: @billz that equation was just an example.

Comment: Perhaps you should try filing police report?

Comment: @billz: That's a division by zero fault. What makes you think it's a stack overflow?

Comment: @chris we have tried double i with very large numbers and the same. But yeah is there a way to stop it from being optimised out other then just printing?

Comment: Just turn off the optimizer, you don't need it.

Comment: Optimization off, while(true) loop round counter code.

Comment: Seriously no up-votes for the awesome title?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CPU Intensive Calculation Examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693197/cpu-intensive-calculation-examples)

Comment: @EJP, no i dont think so. This was a long time ago, but it was more about why this code was being compiled out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function takes no inputs and provides no outputs. So the compiler easily figures out that it does nothing.

I suggest that in your loop you modify a global variable, preferably declared volatile. Then the compiler will not be able to assume that it is not used.

Also, if the processor is fast, you'll need more than a 10000 iteration loop to get any meaningful CPU usage.

You might want to look at some of the benchmarking code out there - dhrystone is one.

Answer (score 5):

Just return `j` from your function and do something with it in the caller. But this is a bad way to stress out a processor because it loads only a very limited subset of the processor. Depending on why you want the load the processor (Do you want to make sure it's working? Do you want to heat it as much as possible?) you should pick a program specifically designed to do what you want. [Prime95](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime95) is a common one.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the '[volatile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable)' keyword on your variables. This is ofcourse, ignoring the fact that you'd need to do a lot more to stress out your computer. You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391601/13760) useful, though I would take the warning on that code very seriously.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to stress the processor:

```
tan(atan(tan(atan(tan(atan(tan(atan(tan(atan(tan(atan(tan(atan(tan(atan(tan(atan(tan(atan(tan(atan(0.5d))))))))))))))))))))));
```

Add a whole lot more levels, and put it into a loop.

This was a soak-test for the PDP-11 many years ago.

Comment: nice! that stresses me out, let alone the computer.