# Service times directly proportional to number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, performance-testing, scheduling, cpu-usage

My system is i5-Dual core with hyper-threading. Windows show me 4 processors.  When i run a single optimized cpu-bound task by a single thread at a time its service time always display arround 35ms. But when i  handover 2 tasks to 2 threads simultanously their service times display arround 70ms. I want to ask that my system have 4 processors then why does service times are arround 70 in case of 2 threads running teir tasks whereas 2 threads should run on 2 processors without any scheduling overhead.The codes are as follows.

CPU-Bound Task is as follows.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CpuBoundJob  implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

         BigInteger factValue = BigInteger.ONE;
            long t1=System.nanoTime();

            for ( int i = 2; i <= 2000; i++){
              factValue = factValue.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
            }
        long t2=System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("Service Time(ms)="+((double)(t2-t1)/1000000));
    }

}
```

Thread that runs a task is as follows.

```
public class TaskRunner extends Thread {
    CpuBoundJob job=new CpuBoundJob();
    public void run(){

        job.run();
    }
}
```

And Finally, main class is as follows.

```
public class Test2 {
int numberOfThreads=100;//warmup code for JIT
public Test2(){
    for(int i=1;i<=numberOfThreads;i++){//warmup code for JIT
        TaskRunner t=new TaskRunner();
        t.start();
        }
    try{
    Thread.sleep(5000);// wait a little bit
    }catch(Exception e){}
    System.out.println("Warmed up completed! now start benchmarking");
    System.out.println("First run single thread at a time");

    try{//wait for the thread to complete
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        //run only one thread at a time
            TaskRunner t1=new TaskRunner();
            t1.start();


    try{//wait for the thread to complete
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        }catch(Exception e){}

    //Now run 2 threads simultanously at a time

    System.out.println("Now run 3 thread at a time");


        for(int i=1;i<=3;i++){//run 2 thread at a time
            TaskRunner t2=new TaskRunner();
            t2.start();


            }


}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test2();    
    }
```

Final output:

> Warmed up completed! now start benchmarking First run single thread at
>   a time Service Time(ms)=5.829112 Now run 2 thread at a time Service
>   Time(ms)=6.518721 Service Time(ms)=10.364269 Service
>   Time(ms)=10.272689

Comment: "I expect 4 threads should run by 4 processors at a time without any overhead." You expect that there are *only* 4 threads running on the computer?

Comment: No! I mean to say that  4 is not so large value that it increases scheduling overhead

Comment: As i read that in case of Cpu-Bound tasks thread pool size should be equal to number of processors.

Comment: otherwise context switch overhead will increase and service time will suffer

Comment: Try using Thread Pool  with Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)

Comment: Same case with Thread Pool too.

Comment: I wouldnt use thread.sleep, instead I would try join

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. I'm not going to try to make sense of this otherwise and I'm sure others feel the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I timed this in a variety of scenarios, and with a slightly modified task, got times of ~45 ms with one thread and ~60 ms for two threads. So, even in this example, in one second, one thread can complete about 22 tasks, but two threads can complete 33 tasks.

However, if you run a task that doesn't tax the garbage collector so grievously, you should see the performance increase you expect: two threads complete twice as many tasks. Here is my version of your test program.

Note that I made one significant change to your task (`DirtyTask`): `n` was always 0, because you cast the result of `Math.random()` to an `int` (which is zero), and *then* multiplied by 13.

Then I added a `CleanTask` that doesn't generate any new objects for the garbage collector to handle. Please test and report the results on your machine. On mine, I got this:

```
Testing "clean" task.
Average task time: one thread = 46 ms; two threads = 45 ms
Testing "dirty" task.
Average task time: one thread = 41 ms; two threads = 62 ms
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

final class Parallels
{

  private static final int RUNS = 10;

  public static void main(String... argv)
    throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println("Testing \"clean\" task.");
    flavor(CleanTask::new);
    System.out.println("Testing \"dirty\" task.");
    flavor(DirtyTask::new);
  }

  private static void flavor(Supplier<Callable<Long>> tasks)
    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
  {
    ExecutorService warmup = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
      warmup.submit(tasks.get());
    warmup.shutdown();
    warmup.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    ExecutorService workers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    long t1 = test(1, tasks, workers);
    long t2 = test(2, tasks, workers);
    System.out.printf("Average task time: one thread = %d ms; two threads = %d ms%n", t1 / (1 * RUNS), t2 / (2 * RUNS));
    workers.shutdown();
  }

  private static long test(int n, Supplier<Callable<Long>> tasks, ExecutorService workers)
    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
  {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < RUNS; ++i) {
      List<Callable<Long>> batch = new ArrayList<>(n);
      for (int t = 0; t < n; ++t)
        batch.add(tasks.get());
      List<Future<Long>> times = workers.invokeAll(batch);
      for (Future<Long> f : times)
        sum += f.get();
    }
    return TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(sum);
  }

  /**
   * Do something on the CPU without creating any garbage, and return the 
   * elapsed time.
   */
  private static class CleanTask
    implements Callable<Long>
  {
    @Override
    public Long call()
    {
      long time = System.nanoTime();
      long x = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 15_000_000; i++)
        x ^= ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong();
      if (x == 0)
        throw new IllegalStateException();
      return System.nanoTime() - time;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Do something on the CPU that creates a lot of garbage, and return the 
   * elapsed time.
   */
  private static class DirtyTask
    implements Callable<Long>
  {
    @Override
    public Long call()
    {
      long time = System.nanoTime();
      String s = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++)
        s += (int) (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble() * 13);
      if (s.length() == 10_000)
        throw new IllegalStateException();
      return System.nanoTime() - time;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer.  The reason the slow down is occurring is because the OP is creating so much garbage which will force the GC to consume the valuable CPU time the OP desires.

Comment: No! I have checked it too. I just commented the statement that contains random and i just used s+="*"; and still the service time is double

Comment: @FaisalBahadur You can change where the contention is, yes. If you *eliminate* contention, then the service time won't double.

Comment: @FaisalBahadur I don't really understand your comment, but I will say that if you use `s += "*"`, you are creating large numbers of large `String` instances and putting a heavy load on the garbage collector. It has nothing to do with `Math.random()`; as you can see I don't use an random number generator that is shared across threads but still see something like the behavior you describe.

Comment: @FaisalBahadur In other words, you don't have 2 threads running, you have 3 or more---two application threads and at least one GC thread running a lot.

Comment: Yes you are true. But I am changing the code to supply new version that dont contains strings and report you what happen wait

Comment: This time i run 3 threads in parallel. 2 threads are still have double service times only one is arround 5. What is the reason while i have 4 processors

Comment: @FaisalBahadur The reason is that you are still churning the garbage collector, so you have additional threads competing for your processors. You just replaced new `String` objects with new `BigInteger` objects. However, your throughput is still increasing with more threads, just not linearly.

Comment: Yes u r absolutely right! Plz tell me what type of code i should use so that garbage collector dont interfere

Comment: @FaisalBahadur I gave an example in my answer of a CPU-intensive task that won't be optimized away by JIT or create any GC activity: `CleanTask` This can be used for testing purposes. Of course, to do your real work, your task will generate garbage or not as needed. Just be aware that GC is some overhead that will diminish throughput from the theoretical maximum.

Comment: Is ThreadLocalRandom can be accessd by multiple threads in atomic manner. is this synchronized?

Comment: @FaisalBahadur `ThreadLocalRandom` creates a distinct random number generator for each thread so that there is no sharing or contention of the RNG; no synchronization is necessary, because it is restricted to a single thread.

Comment: So nice of u but 1 last question. i have 4 processors and when i run 20 threads simultanously to run their Cpu-Bound jobs then their service times will definetly increase. What are main reasons of this. Plz help to clear my concept

Comment: Is this only due to time slicing(i.e.) context switch overhead?

Comment: @FaisalBahadur Once you remove sources of contention, your computer still can only do so much work per unit time. It really is that simple.

Comment: @FaisalBahadur It is a consequence of [Amdahl's law.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law) When you don't exercise the garbage collector, the task is almost completely parallel-izable, so you see almost linear throughput increase for the first few processors. But apparently the GC load cannot be parallel-ized as effectively, so you see sublinear improvements with additional processors.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        int n=(int)Math.random()*13;
        s+=name.valueOf(n);
        //s+="*";
    }
```

This code is a tight spin around a resource that can only be accessed by one thread at a time. So each thread just has to wait for the other to release the random number generator so that it can access it.

As the [docs for `Math.random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) say:

> When this method is first called, it creates a single new pseudorandom-number generator, exactly as if by the expression
>
> new java.util.Random()
>
> This new pseudorandom-number generator is used thereafter for all calls to this method and is used nowhere else.
>
> This method is properly synchronized to allow correct use by more than one thread. However, **if many threads need to generate pseudorandom numbers at a great rate, it may reduce contention for each thread to have its own pseudorandom-number generator**.

Comment: Even when using `ThreadLocalRandom`, the average time is about 50% longer when running two threads concurrently. Good catch though.

Comment: @erickson For the very same reason, contention in the string operation.

Comment: Ok u comment the statement that contains random and uncomment S+="*"; U will see the same result

Comment: Random is not a problem here

Comment: @FaisalBahadur Random *is* the problem here. If you comment out random, then of course random will no longer be the problem and the problem will then be contention in the memory management of the string concatenation. (Your testing methodology is woefully insufficient!)

Comment: Contention in which string operation? I don't understand.

Comment: Ok If u think this is the case then u try any other code without string and u will see service time is double in case of 2 simultaneous threads

Comment: @FaisalBahadur If you present an example of such code, I'll explain why, just as I did here. It is very difficult to minimize contention between threads and it's not unusual to fix the problem in one place only to have it crop up someplace else.

Comment: Sorry i am late due to electricity load shedding here. Any how i have provided the examples above with an easy code edition plz run above example and tell me if i am wrong

Comment: I have a new code should i edit the code in the question or i should put a new question?

Comment: @FaisalBahadur I think you can add it to the question, since it is substantially the same question. Likely you moved the contention to garbage collection, but I'd have to see the code to be sure.

Comment: This time i run 3 threads in parallel. 2 threads are still have double service times only one is arround 5. What is the reason while i have 4 processors

Comment: @FaisalBahadur You have two physical cores. You can run four threads at once, but if two threads share a physical core they will take about a 25%-50% performance hit. Here, the two threads are trying to do exactly the same kinds of things, so the performance hit will be at the very high end. Hyper-threading works great if one thread is doing floating point math and the other is doing integer, or one thread is doing integer math and the other is accessing memory. But if both threads are limited by the same execution resources, hyper-threading doesn't gain you much.