# 4 processors, 2 simultaneous thread running, Why service time increases

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, throughput, response-time

I want to clear my concept on thread scheduling. I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748495/service-times-directly-proportional-to-number-of-threads) question before but due to no response i am trying to ask it in convinient manner My system has 4 processors when I run single CPU-bound task on a thread it completes in around 30ms. When I run 2 CPU-bound tasks on two threads they complete in around 70ms.

Why do 2 tasks running on two threads take twice the time?

CPU-bound task:

```
public class CpuBoundJob3  implements Runnable {
    //long t1,t2;
    public void run() {

            long t1=System.nanoTime();
            String s = "";
            String name="faisalbahadur";
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)//6000 for 15ms 10000 for 35ms 12000 for 50ms
            {
                int n=(int)Math.random()*13;
                s+=name.valueOf(n);
                //s+="*";
            }
          long t2=System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("Service Time(ms)="+((double)(t2-t1)/1000000));
    }


}
```

Thread to run a task:

```
public class TaskRunner extends Thread {
    CpuBoundJob3 job=new CpuBoundJob3();
    public void run(){

    job.run();  
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Test2 {
int numberOfThreads=100;//for JIT Warmup
public Test2(){
    for(int i=1;i<=numberOfThreads;i++){for JIT Warmup
        TaskRunner t=new TaskRunner();
        t.start();
        }
    try{
    Thread.sleep(5000);// wait a little bit
    }catch(Exception e){}
    System.out.println("Warmed up completed! now start benchmarking");
    System.out.println("First run single thread at a time");

        //run only one thread at a time
            TaskRunner t1=new TaskRunner();
            t1.start();


    try{//wait for the thread to complete
        Thread.sleep(500);
        }catch(Exception e){}

    //Now run 2 threads simultanously at a time

    System.out.println("Now run 2 thread at a time");


        for(int i=1;i<=2;i++){//run 2 thread at a time
            TaskRunner t2=new TaskRunner();
            t2.start();


            }


}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test2();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Your threads are probably competing for system resources

Comment: Try to rule out the overhead involved in the threads creation.

Comment: No! Same is the case with thread pool.

Comment: Are you also using a thread pool when testing the single thread case?

Comment: I have tested it. 1 thread in pool 1 task:service time arround 35ms. 2 threads in pool 2 tasks:service time arround 70.

Comment: Don't create new, worse versions of your previous questions.

Comment: So overhead is probably not your problem. You should try executing the tasks multiple times to get a better insight. Try running 1000 tasks with one thread, 2000 tasks with one thread and 2000 tasks with two threads and see what happens.

Comment: Kayaman i am trying to get the answer in some way . Plz help if u can.

Comment: Kayaman i see the answer of previous question right now!

Comment: It was answered too late but I got the point.

Answer (score -1):

Another phenomenon that sometimes happens is "false sharing". This happens when one thread reads from the same cache line (typically 64 consecutive bytes, depending on the system) that another thread is writing. This is bad for the cache, and this slows down memory access.

When I wrote my first multithreaded program this happened to me as follows: I assigned one thread to operate on the even places of an array, and another thread to operate on the odd places. This is perfectly thread-safe, but very slow, because when thread 1 writes at the array in place #n, thread 2 is reading from place #(n+1), which is the same cache-line as place #n, so the cache keeps getting invalidated.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing

Comment: see this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748495/service-times-directly-proportional-to-number-of-threads/34751497?noredirect=1#comment57254220_34751497