# Why is it that incresing the number of threads upto number of processors increase service times

Tags: java, multithreading, performance-testing

Firstly i am not talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748495/service-times-directly-proportional-to-number-of-threads) question.My question relates to particular case.In case of CPU-Bound task the number of threads should be equal to number of processors. But if running a single thread that run a task completes in X times then Why running 2 threads simultaneously on 4 processor system still increases service time twice whereas there are 2 extra processors.

Comment: it's not true, show us an example.

Comment: Could you perhaps give us some code to work with, or a description of what service you are trying to provide? Are you synchronizing in any way?

Comment: Parallelism has its own overheads that can't be avoided.  For many tasks, parallelizing just hurts performance.  Without more detail on what exactly you're doing we can't tell you whether that's inevitable or not.

Comment: ok wait because of electricity load shedding in our country i was late w8 a little bit

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what these threads are doing. The best advice is to run tests and measure what number of threads would give best performance.

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748495/service-times-directly-proportional-to-number-of-threads